# WooCommerce search form

Tags: forms, search, woocommerce, categories

Been looking for a answer for this for quite some time.
I wonder if it's possible to create a search form that only searches through a specific category with attributes based on radio buttons and a value.

I know that there are filters for woocommerce but I feel that some features are missing for my purpose. This is the structure, and when pressed "search" it will filter the products based on the filled in criteria

```
Type 1:
Attribute 1 (radio button 1)
Attribute 2 (radio button 2)
Attribute 3 (radio button 3)

Type 2:
Attribute 1 (radio button 4)
Attribute 2 (radio button 5)

(text field) VALUE

Search
```

Comment: Have you looked at existing plugins such as this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/instantsearch-for-woocommerce/. If you can find some similar functionality there that would clarify the question a little bit and probably you might be able to use it out of the box for your specific purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I have tried a few plugins and have not found anything that works for my purpose yet.